# How can I have the red label from Google Maps with Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Maps API to create a map on a website with coordinates.
I don't know how I can add the same red label on the marker I can have with a search on Google Maps.

[For example with the Eiffel Tower](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Eiffel+Tower/@48.8583736,2.2922926,17z/data=!4m12!1m6!3m5!1s0x47e66e2964e34e2d:0x8ddca9ee380ef7e0!2sEiffel+Tower!8m2!3d48.8583701!4d2.2944813!3m4!1s0x47e66e2964e34e2d:0x8ddca9ee380ef7e0!8m2!3d48.8583701!4d2.2944813)

I try using the `title` option, but it only displays a label when I click on the marker.

Answer (score 0):

From the [google maps docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers)

```
function initMap() {
  var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () => {
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: "This is DC!"})
    infoWindow.open(map, marker)
  })
}
```

Comment: I imagine you can style the info window afterward.